# How to compare two SQL database table and mark checkbox based on result using php

Tags: php, mysql

Hope you are doing great. So I am working on a automated attendance system using face recognition and I am displaying data through php.
I have a SQL database with the name of **student_db** and there are two tables in it with the name of **mark_attendance** and **student_detail**. Face recognition system recgnize faces and send rollnumber and date on **mark_attendance**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da8Bu.png)

where as **student_detail** consist of whole class students name and rollnumber.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAZ4o.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVd4F.png)

I am displaying name, rollnumber and a checkbox on frontend what I want to do is to mark checkbox aUtomatically if student is present. It should compare data of mark_attendance table with the studet_detail table and mark checkbox.

I AM ATTACHING THE CODE I HAVE TRIED BUT ITS NOT WORKING.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> Attendance </th>
        </tr>
        <?PHP
            include('db_connection.php');
            
            $qry = "SELECT * FROM student_detail";
            $result = mysqli_query($db_con, $qry);

            $ftch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            $markattendance = "SELECT * FROM mark_attendance ";
            $ma = mysqli_query($db_con, $markattendance);


            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
                foreach($result as $r)
                {             
                    $sav = "SELECT * FROM mark_attendance t1
                    JOIN student_detail t2
                    ON t2.rollno = t1.rollno";
                    
                    $sa = mysqli_query($db_con, $sav);
                    $s = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sa);
                    $count = mysqli_num_rows($sa); echo "</b>";
                   
    
                echo "<table><tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$r['Name']."</td>";   
                    //  echo $r['rollno'];
                     echo $s['rollno'];

                        if($count >= 1 && $s['rollno'] == $r['rollno']){
                            echo "<form><td> <input type='checkbox' checked value=".$r['Name']."></td>";
                           
                        }

                        else{
                            echo "<form><td> <input type='checkbox' value=".$r['Name']."></td>";
                        }
                        
                     
                        // echo "<form><td> <input type='checkbox' value=".$r['Name']."></td>";
                        // echo "<td> <input type='text' value=".$r['rollno']."></td></form>";        
                echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
        ?>   
        </table>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Its MARKING only the first data checkbox on db not other after it.

I also have tried with while loop and other stuff but its still not working can you run it on your computer and provide me the working code.

**SORRY FOR THE BAD ENGLISH**

Comment: Inside the `for` loop, the query that you have in the `$sav` variable doesn’t have anything dynamic, so it would always do the same thing. I assume you want to pull from one query (table), loop over the results and pass IDs to subsequent queries?

Comment: I want to compare all the values if the rollnumber is present and mark the "HTML" checkbox as checked.

Comment: I think you have made this more complicated than you need it to be. A single query with a join should get you a table with each student record and the corresponding attendance mark. I would forget about the php and html for a while and just make a query that has the results you need.